# Linq to Select Parent Objects Where Child Objects Dont contain value

Tags: entity-framework, linq

If I have a DB structure like this

```
class Parent {
int ID { get; set; }
string Name { get; set; }
List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child {
int ID { get; set; }
string Name { get; set; }
List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }    
}
```

I want to get a list of all the Parents who have a child whos name is NOT "Dave"

So 
If Parent one has two children called Jack and Jill, I want them

If Parent two has two children called Sam and Dave I dont want them

If Parent three has no children I want them

If Parent four has one child called Steve I want them

If Parent five has one child called Dave, I dont want them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to get a list of all the Parents who have a child whos name is NOT "Dave"

conflicts with Rule #3: *If Parent three has no children I want them*.

The requirement that fits all the rules can be described as:

> get a list of all the Parents who have NO child WITH name "Dave"

which in LINQ translates as:

```
var query = db.Parent.Where(p => !p.Children.Any(c => c.Name == "Dave"));
```